# Automate EC2 and RDS mysql service to reset mysql db

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I have a CRM application (java + Gradle) in Running in AWS Ec2, backend with RDS Mysql database. This is a test app/Environment.

Scenario :

1. CRM app should be stopped.
2. Reset RDS MYSQL database weekly once a day(DB should be truncated and create a new database with same DB name).
3. Then the CRM app has to be deployed.
4. The app will be accessible in public URL.

I need your inputs on how to do this in AWS, with an automated process.

Comment: I wonder if you can just use an API call to restore RDS to a point in time. EC2 can be automated with lambda. Seems like a fairly odd thing to do though, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a test CRM app that is running in AWS free tier for demo purpose.  right now every week, i am manually stopping app, resetting database and  starting the app. This is taking more time. The main intent of this to clear the existing data and make sure app & db is highly available with out any performance issue.

Comment: are you deploying new CRM app every week, and the database must be empty?

Comment: No. I have  a existing CRM app.  application has been hosted in AWS free tier.  Usage of app is heavy. so DB storage is getting filled. so i am  resetting db to make sure it not crossing the free tier limit.

Comment: are you hosting this for your personal use or for work?

Comment: Both. this for learning.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script on the EC2 server that runs on cron script that

1. Truncates the database
2. Pushes a clean database to the server (mysql command line is easy, use Google)
3. Runs "sudo reboot now" on the EC2 server.

This outputs the database, which you'd run once when the server is in the desired initial state

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p (password) > outputfile.sql
```

You might edit it to add "truncate" type commands.

This one loads the data back into the database

```
mysql (dbname)  -h localhost -u root -p (password) < outputfile.sql
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try and update you.